# C++ Bare Boolean Expressions (without an if, while or some other statement)

Tags: c++, boolean

I found the following code as a solution to this online C++ coding problem:

"Problem: Write a program that will find the largest element of an arbitrary array without using any conditional structures: banned { if/if-else/switch/for/while/do/?:-operator }."

```
# include <iostream>
int findMax(int * array, size_t size)
{
    int max, other;
    size > 2 && (other = findMax(array + 1, size - 1)) || (other = array[1]);
    other > array[0] && (max = other) || (max = array[0]);
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {3, 1, 4, 15, 9, 2, 6, 5, 35, 8, 97, 93, 23, 84, 62, 64, 33, 83, 27, 950, 28, 841, 971, 69, 39, 937, 510};
    std::cout << findMax(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My QUESTION:
How can we do something like this in C++?

```
size > 2 && (other = findMax(array + 1, size - 1)) || (other = array[1]);
```

I only have limited experience in C++, and I haven't seen anything like this in java.
Can someone please explain how we can have boolean expressions running bare without an if, while or some other statement.
I googled it a lot, but couldn't find anything useful. Thanks a lot.

---

EDIT:
Thanks, everyone for the replies. I understand the concept of short-circuiting. But normally I'd use it more like this:

```
1. if (boolean1 && boolean2 || boolean3)
2.  // do sth;
3. while(boolean1 || boolean2)
4.  // loop;
5. return boolean1 && boolean2;
```

Now I am more of a java user. So I tried somethin like the following in my java code:

```
size > 2 && (other = findMax(array + 1, size - 1)) || (other = array[1]);
```

But it just gave a compile-time error. I guess java is stricter on these rules.
Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: use a goto statement :p

Comment: This is taking advantage of short-circuit evaluation of `&&` and `||`.

Comment: This is not something you would probably ever want to do other than to satisfy silly "requirements
"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the concept of short-circuiting, which is available in java also. I also know it's the above code is not of much practical use. But I am curious about this feature which I have never seen before. Is there any post or thread where I can read more about using boolean expressions outside if or loop statements?

Comment: There is nothing special in boolean expressions in C++. You can write `1;` and it's not an error. You just create an anonymous variable equal to one and discard it right away. Here you do the same, only assigning value is more complicated.

Comment: @DarthHunterix: Strictly speaking, there is no "anonymous variable". The expression `1` is evaluated and the result is discarded; the value is never stored anywhere.

Comment: Don't you have to store the value somewhere during the evaluation process? Anyway, the compiler would remove this code anyway, so it's a moot point.

Comment: @DarthHunterix: The C standard doesn't describe it in those terms. The result of an expression might exist in memory or in a register, but that's an implementation detail. In the semantics described by the C standard, the value just ... exists (and can be stored in an object via an assignment).

Comment: Then I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It's called short circuiting. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Basically, if you have a `&&` or `||` operator if there is no point in checking next value, it's never executed.

Consider this statement:

```
isCondition1Fulfilled(a) || isCondition2Fulfilled(a)
```

If `isCondition1Fulfilled(a)` is true, then the whole expression is true no matter what, so calling `isCondition2Fulfilled(a)` is only a waste of time. So it is never called.

Here is another one:

```
isCondition3Fulfilled(a) && isCondition4Fulfilled(a)
```

If `isCondition3Fulfilled(a)` is false, then there is no point in calling `isCondition4Fulfilled(a)`

Your program takes advantage of it, for example:

```
size > 2 && (other = findMax(array + 1, size - 1)) || (other = array[1]);
```

If `size` is lower or equal 2, then the rest is never called. If not, but `findMax(array + 1, size - 1)` turns out to be positive, `(other = array[1])` is not called.

Figure out the rest yourself :)

EDIT (A response to EDIT in OP):

Java is indeed a lot stricter in this case. In C/C++ pretty much anything and go into if statement: int, pointer, string, constant number, char, etc. But as we discussed with @Keith Thompson, you can just place any statement like that in a line of code. It will just be evaluated and immediately discarded.